# Getting injected service from controller prototype

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to optimize my code by using prototype inheritance in a controller used by a directive. Since directives can be invoked several times, I thought it might be a good idea to do this. But my controllers prototype is depending on injected services, which angular complains it does not have access to.

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myModule', [])
        .factory('MyService', MyService)
        .controller('myController', MyController);

    // My service
    function MyService() {
        return {
            getMyStuff: getMyStuff
        }

        function getMyStuff() {
            return 'stuff';
        }
    }

    // My controller
    MyController.$inject = ['MyService'];
    function MyController(MyService) {
        var ctrl = this;
        // Provide some value to the template
    }

    MyController.prototype = {
        getStuff: function () {
            return MyService.getMyStuff(); // This does not work. MyService is not available from the prototype. Why??
        }
    }
})(angular);
```

How can I make the MyService available to the prototype?

I've even tried to use the $injector service in order to get it, but

```
getStuff: function () {
    return angular.injector(['myModule']).get('MyService').getMyStuff();
}
```

complains even more...

Comment: this.MyService = MyService?

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. But that would leak the entire service into the scope. And I don't think that is good practice.